# Как добавить пробел в EditText после каждого третьего символа?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Друзья, подскажите, как мне в EditText добавлять пробел после каждого третьего числа. Грубо говоря у меня есть несколько EditText'ов в которых клиенты вводят цены. Мне нужно их привести в привычный для человека вид - # ### (1 000), или ## ### (15 750). Причем форматировать нужно прямо во время ввода то есть используя mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()). Я перерыл интернет и найти решение не получается, то ли какую то маску готовую использовать, то ли Regex, то ли как то разбивать на символы строку и впиливать пробелы самому. Если есть android разработчики, подскажите, может сталкивались с такой задачей.

Comment: Попробуйте вот эту библиотеку: https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-android

Comment: Юрий, маски не будут работать по той логике которая мне нужна. Мне нужно при вводе значений превращать их в : 1 000, 10 000, 100 000, 1 000 000. Маски не позволяют делать такое, добавлять пробелы после каждого третьего символа, которые считаться должны с конца, а не сначала. Маска выдаст следующее: 100 0, 100 00, 100 000, 100 000 0. Такие форматы значений не нужны.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542211/how-to-format-number-in-android-edittext-after-realtime-editing

Answer (score 0):

Берите [MaskedEditText](https://github.com/toshikurauchi/MaskedEditText)

Форматирование на уровне лейаута делается примерно так:

```
<br.com.sapereaude.maskedEditText.MaskedEditText 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    mask:mask="###.###.###-##"
/>
```

Comment: Это не сработает. Допустим маска такая (app:mask="### ### ###"), я ввожу 1000 , у меня получится 100 0, ввожу 10000 - получится 100 00. Маска не подстраивается под вводимое число